# Connecting SpringBoot Java app to external mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to connect my basic local maven springboot java app to an external mongodb.

Even with just trying to use mongo console itself it took a long time to figure out the syntax. Example below i managed to finally connect with (I run via a batch script)

```
...\mongo.exe "mongodb://serv1.unix.abc:27018,serv2.unix.abc:27018,ser3.unix.abc:27018/test?replicaSet=asdfg01h" --authenticationMechanism=GSSAPI --authenticationDatabase=$external --username="user@THATDOMAIN.COM" --password="password" -ssl --sslCAFile=C:\mongo\ca.pem
```

(Using mongo v 4.2.8 enterprise)

On java side (using jdk11, maven 3.6.1, springboot 2.4.0)  it was easy enough to connect to a local mongo instance.
I just needed to add a basic uri in my application-local.yml:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/localtest
```

And just add below code:

```
@Autowired
private MongoClient mongoClient;
..
..
MongoDatabase myDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("localtest");
```

But I dont really have any idea how to connect to the same external database as that mongo console script I wrote above. Using the uri only doesnt seem to work. I think it is because of the complexity given there are a lot of variables to account for.

- replicaset (3 hosts)
- GSSAPI authentication mechanism
- $external authenticationdatabase
- provide both username and password (GSSAPI example codes I've seen dont mention password anywhere for some reason)
- enable SSL
- and point to a ssl CA pem file

I've seen various examples that make use of MongoClientOptions
MongoCredential
MongoClientSettings

But I keep struggling to get it to work, especially when some articles use deprecated features. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using spring data, this is how I connect:

> spring.data.mongodb.database=database_name_here
> spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://CN=some.name.com@some.domain.com:55017/?authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&tls=true&authSource=$external